# UICollectionView with images : Memory increases up to 1.75 GB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

My iPhone App displays a CollectionView with about 100 Images separated by Headers. The Images have a size from about 200Kb. In the debug navigator the memory increases up to 1.75 GB while scrolling the CollectionView. It still runs smooth, but there must be a reason for that.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picturesMoon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picturesEarth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picturesVenus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picturesMars;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *plistDict;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *picName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyCustomCell *myCell;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Milkyway.png"]];

    self.plistDict=[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Praxis" ofType:@"plist"]] objectForKey:@"Universe"];

    // Pictures Moon
    picturesMoon = [self.plistDict objectForKey:@"Moon"];

    // Pictures Earth
    picturesEarth = [self.plistDict objectForKey:@"Earth"];

   // Pictures Mars
   picturesMars = [self.plistDict objectForKey:@"Mars"];
}


 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {



     self.myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     // Sections
     switch (indexPath.section) {
         case 0:
             self.myCell.imageInCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[picturesMoon objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
             break;
         case 1:
             self.myCell.imageInCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[picturesEarth objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
        break;
         case 2:
             self.myCell.imageInCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[picturesMars objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
             break;
         case 3:
             self.myCell.imageInCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[picturesVenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
             break;
       default:
              break;
      }
      return self.myCell
 }

 - (UICollectionReusableView *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     // Header for Sections
     HeaderCollectionView *myHeaderView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"Header"   forIndexPath:indexPath];
     switch (indexPath.section) {
         case 0:
             myHeaderView.labelOutlet.text = @"Moon";
             break;
         case 1:
             myHeaderView.labelOutlet.text = @"Earth";
             break;
 ...
 ...
          default:
             break
      }
 return myHeaderView;
 }
```

MyCustomCell is just a few line of Code

```
 #import "MyCustomCell.h"

 @implementation MyCustomCell
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         // Initialization code
     }  
     return self;
 }
```

and the Header for MyCustomCell just

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface MyCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageInCell;
 @end
```

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at allocations.  This profiling tool has fields for total allocations and active/destroyed allocations.  My guess is that you are reading the total allocations.  That is a completely understandable number assuming you have been scrolling back and forth a lot.  Worry about the current active memory.  If that gets too large then fix it, if not you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the images. The large memory footprint isn't necessarily a problem, as the cache will be automatically purged if memory is too low. That said, if you want to avoid caching, you can use another method to load the images, for example:

```
NSString *imageName = [picturesMars objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"PNG"]; // PNG, or whatever file tile you are actually using
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
self.myCell.imageInCell.image = image;
```